# Unable to put() + get() larger DataFrames in a Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

The code below simulates a problem with multiprocessing I am facing.

There are two functions - **f1** and **f2** - which return (pandas) dataframes with **n** rows to a calling function **run_fns**(n). The two functions are to be run in parallel.

The code works fine for smaller vales of **n** (eg n <= 700), but freezes for larger values of **n** (say n >= 7000).

I have tried calling **Queue** using **Queue**([maxsize]) with various maxsize values including the default, 0, -1 and many other numbers small and large with no change in this behaviour.

Any solutions, workarounds or alternate approaches would be very welcome. And I have a secondary question : Do I really need to include

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

somewhere? If so where?

*The code:
f1 returns n rows and 3 columns, f2 returns n rows and 5 columns. The dataframes are built with randomly generated integers.*

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def run_fns(n):
    """Run p1 and p2 in parallel, and get the returned dataframes."""
    q1 = Queue()
    q2 = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=f1, args=(n, q1))
    p2 = Process(target=f2, args=(n, q2))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    df1 = q1.get()
    df2 = q2.get()
    return df1, df2


def f1(n, q):
    """Create a dataframe with n rows and 3 columns."""
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(n * 3, size=(n, 3)))
    q.put(df)


def f2(n, q):
    """Create a dataframe with n rows and 5 columns."""
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(n * 5, size=(n, 5)))
    q.put(df)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing a typical issue which is documented in the multiprocessing [programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines).

> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe. (The child process can call the Queue.cancel_join_thread method of the queue to avoid this behaviour.)
>
> This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure that processes which have put items on the queue will terminate.

You need to make sure you get the data before joining the processes.

```
# start the processes
p1.start()
p2.start()
# drain the queues
df1 = q1.get()
df2 = q2.get()
# then join the queues
p1.join()
p2.join()

return df1, df2
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, @noxdafox. I had made the incorrect assumption that I would need to place the joins before the get statements, based on a couple of examples I had seen.

Comment: This is not working for me... it still seems to be blocking from an underlying process